# Where can I find a complete list of goods affected by NAFTA?

Tags: international-trade, data-request, agriculture

I am looking for the list of goods that NAFTA, preferably in the format of what is subject to tariff reduction.

I have found a few potential leads, but none seem to be exhaustive: 
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nafta.asp

https://fas.org/sgp/crs/row/R44875.pdf

https://aic.ucdavis.edu/pub/briefs/brief21.pdf

https://aic.ucdavis.edu/2003/02/01/role-of-nafta-in-california-agriculture-a-brief-review/

Here is the agreement in full (if someone is familiar, perhaps they could point me to a specific chapter?):

https://www.nafta-sec-alena.org/Home/Texts-of-the-Agreement/North-American-Free-Trade-Agreement?mvid=2

Comment: Over time links often rot. To make this question valuable to others, please describe or cite the documents you link to.

Comment: Updated according to your comments - good point!

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer You did not name any of the documents you linked to, please do so.

Comment: @Giskard updated !

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by @Bkay, these linked documents are likely to rot. For future users, the keyword I was missing when searching for these documents was 'tariff schedule'. The below links to 2019 tariff schedules. I suggest that in the future a user search:

'YEAR tariff schedule COUNTRYOFINTEREST'

It may also be useful to specify the trade agreement of interest.

For USA: Harmonized Tariff Schedule 2019 Revision 2

Link: https://hts.usitc.gov/current

For Canada: Customs Tariff by Chapter (Customs Tariff 2019-1)

Link: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/trade-commerce/tariff-tarif/2019/html/tblmod-1-eng.html

For Mexico (and all three): Mexico Import Export Codes

Link:http://www.siicex-caaarem.org.mx/

Chapters of interest will vary by personal use.